# Is there any minimum Server requirement for Windows Server to Host a MVC3 WebApp

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, server

Is there any minimum Server requirement for Windows Server to Host a MVC3 WebApp. I know it needs IIS 7. Other than this any other Hardware requirements (i.e) RAM,Processor, etc.

I googled it,but i couldn't get answer for my question.

My Web App will be used by 5000 users, Randomly 100 users will be using @ a time. Any Configuration suggestions???

Comment: You don't need IIS7.  IIS6 will work (However, IIS6 is only available on XP and Windows Server 2003, XP is already end of lifed and Windows Server 2003 will be EOL by mid-next year, so I would not suggest going this route).

Comment: I think there is no official source for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ram: 512MB and Processor: Duel Core is enough